# Buildbot: How do I skip a build if got_revision is the same as the last run?

Tags: buildbot

I have a nightly build that is triggered by another checkin build.  The trigger from checkin build is predicated by the success of that build.  In other words, got_revision for the nightly build will always point to the last passing checkin build.

I'd like to skip the nightly build if got_revision is the same as last build.  What would the master config look like?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

See: http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/cfg-schedulers.html

Example:

```
c['schedulers'].append(
    schedulers.Nightly(name='BeforeWork',
                       branch=`default`,
                       builderNames=['builder1'],
                       dayOfWeek=0,
                       hour=[6,8],
                       minute=23,
                       onlyIfChanged=True))
```

`onlyIfChanged=True` should do the trick =>  makes sure to only perform the build when someone has committed code in the interim.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using NightlyTriggerable now.  If there are no new triggered revision, it won't be run when the schedule time occurs.  However, there are times when someone forces a run on a particular revision, and I don't want an automatic trigger to run the something right after.  In that case I ended up using doStepIf callback.  I will post the code.

Answer (score 0):

Following code can be used for doStepIf callback.  It will skip a run if the last build was same revision and passed.  This could be extended to search for all previous builds instead of the last run.  Also, in my original question I asked for got_revision.  In doStepIf it's best not to use got_revision because not all builds will result in valid got_revision.

```
def do_step_if(step):
    cur_status = step.build.build_status
    prev_status = cur_status.getPreviousBuild()
    # this is the first build
    if prev_status==None:
        return True
    # never skip if this is a forced run
    if cur_status.getProperty("revision")==None or cur_status.getProperty("revision")=="":
        return True
    # got_revision won't be set if update step wasn't run, so better to use revision
    if prev_status.getResults()==SUCCESS and prev_status.getProperty("revision")==cur_status.getProperty("revision"):
        return False
    return True
```